# How to do some rule in this type of datepicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this type of datepicker.

[image]

I usually use Bootstrap datepicker, but I am unfamiliar with this one. I have difficulties setting some rule. Rules that I'dlike to do are:

1. Disable Weekends
2. Set defaultdate when click today = Today +3 (Exclude weekends)

Some default jquery script come along with this date picker :

```
function Datepicker() {
this._curInst = null; // The current instance in use
this._keyEvent = false; // If the last event was a key event
this._disabledInputs = []; // List of date picker inputs that have been disabled
this._datepickerShowing = false; // True if the popup picker is showing , false if not
this._inDialog = false; // True if showing within a "dialog", false if not
this._mainDivId = "ui-datepicker-div"; // The ID of the main datepicker division
this._inlineClass = "ui-datepicker-inline"; // The name of the inline marker class
this._appendClass = "ui-datepicker-append"; // The name of the append marker class
this._triggerClass = "ui-datepicker-trigger"; // The name of the trigger marker class
this._dialogClass = "ui-datepicker-dialog"; // The name of the dialog marker class
this._disableClass = "ui-datepicker-disabled"; // The name of the disabled covering marker class
this._unselectableClass = "ui-datepicker-unselectable"; // The name of the unselectable cell marker class
this._currentClass = "ui-datepicker-current-day"; // The name of the current day marker class
this._dayOverClass = "ui-datepicker-days-cell-over"; // The name of the day hover marker class
this.regional = []; // Available regional settings, indexed by language code
this.regional[ "" ] = { // Default regional settings
    closeText: "Done", // Display text for close link
    prevText: "Prev", // Display text for previous month link
    nextText: "Next", // Display text for next month link
    currentText: "Today", // Display text for current month link
    monthNames: [ "January","February","March","April","May","June",
        "July","August","September","October","November","December" ], // Names of months for drop-down and formatting
    monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ], // For formatting
    dayNames: [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ], // For formatting
    dayNamesShort: [ "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" ], // For formatting
    dayNamesMin: [ "Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa" ], // Column headings for days starting at Sunday
    weekHeader: "Wk", // Column header for week of the year
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", // See format options on parseDate
    firstDay: 0, // The first day of the week, Sun = 0, Mon = 1, ...
    isRTL: false, // True if right-to-left language, false if left-to-right
    showMonthAfterYear: false, // True if the year select precedes month, false for month then year
    yearSuffix: "" // Additional text to append to the year in the month headers
};
this._defaults = { // Global defaults for all the date picker instances
    showOn: "focus", // "focus" for popup on focus,
        // "button" for trigger button, or "both" for either
    showAnim: "fadeIn", // Name of jQuery animation for popup
    showOptions: {}, // Options for enhanced animations
    defaultDate: null, // Used when field is blank: actual date,
        // +/-number for offset from today, null for today
    appendText: "", // Display text following the input box, e.g. showing the format
    buttonText: "...", // Text for trigger button
    buttonImage: "", // URL for trigger button image
    buttonImageOnly: false, // True if the image appears alone, false if it appears on a button
    hideIfNoPrevNext: false, // True to hide next/previous month links
        // if not applicable, false to just disable them
    navigationAsDateFormat: false, // True if date formatting applied to prev/today/next links
    gotoCurrent: false, // True if today link goes back to current selection instead
    changeMonth: false, // True if month can be selected directly, false if only prev/next
    changeYear: false, // True if year can be selected directly, false if only prev/next
    yearRange: "c-10:c+10", // Range of years to display in drop-down,
        // either relative to today's year (-nn:+nn), relative to currently displayed year
        // (c-nn:c+nn), absolute (nnnn:nnnn), or a combination of the above (nnnn:-n)
    showOtherMonths: false, // True to show dates in other months, false to leave blank
    selectOtherMonths: false, // True to allow selection of dates in other months, false for unselectable
    showWeek: false, // True to show week of the year, false to not show it
    calculateWeek: this.iso8601Week, // How to calculate the week of the year,
        // takes a Date and returns the number of the week for it
    shortYearCutoff: "+10", // Short year values < this are in the current century,
        // > this are in the previous century,
        // string value starting with "+" for current year + value
    minDate: null, // The earliest selectable date, or null for no limit
    maxDate: null, // The latest selectable date, or null for no limit
    duration: "fast", // Duration of display/closure
    beforeShowDay: null, // Function that takes a date and returns an array with
        // [0] = true if selectable, false if not, [1] = custom CSS class name(s) or "",
        // [2] = cell title (optional), e.g. $.datepicker.noWeekends
    beforeShow: null, // Function that takes an input field and
        // returns a set of custom settings for the date picker
    onSelect: null, // Define a callback function when a date is selected
    onChangeMonthYear: null, // Define a callback function when the month or year is changed
    onClose: null, // Define a callback function when the datepicker is closed
    numberOfMonths: 1, // Number of months to show at a time
    showCurrentAtPos: 0, // The position in multipe months at which to show the current month (starting at 0)
    stepMonths: 1, // Number of months to step back/forward
    stepBigMonths: 12, // Number of months to step back/forward for the big links
    altField: "", // Selector for an alternate field to store selected dates into
    altFormat: "", // The date format to use for the alternate field
    constrainInput: true, // The input is constrained by the current date format
    showButtonPanel: false, // True to show button panel, false to not show it
    autoSize: false, // True to size the input for the date format, false to leave as is
    disabled: false // The initial disabled state
};
$.extend( this._defaults, this.regional[ "" ] );
this.regional.en = $.extend( true, {}, this.regional[ "" ] );
this.regional[ "en-US" ] = $.extend( true, {}, this.regional.en );
this.dpDiv = datepicker_bindHover( $( "<div id='" + this._mainDivId + "' class='ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all'></div>" ) );
```

}

My HTML:

```
<div id="tgl" class="form-group date_2">
                        <input type="text" id="tgl_srt" name="tgl_srt" class="form-control date" placeholder="Tertera" 
                         style="width:100%" required />
                    </div>
```

Javascript needed by the datepicker:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/inspinia/js/jquery-2.1.1.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Any helps/reference sites are greatly appreciated

Comment: *"I have this type of datepicker"* ... so where is link to the docs? We shouldn't have to guess where it comes from. If the docs aren't clear to you or the features needed aren't supported, use one that has what you need

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know where to get that online. It come along with the project file I working on.

Comment: Ok...is jQueryUI which is well documented. Could have figured that out by opening the script file. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I have post the date picker script part. As reminder, the datepicker work perfectly. I just do not know how to set up some rules.

Comment: Ok...well the api docs are well written and have examples for all methods...start there using links I just posted. Also edit question to identify it is jQuery UI. I just added a tag for it also

Comment: I've do this `$( "#tgl_srt" ).datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});` but weekends still show up

Comment: Works fine here https://plnkr.co/edit/NeAzCTfM8ftgUrEeTMrf?p=preview. What version is it? Can check in the file

Comment: @charlietfl It's 1.12.1. Um, I use `<div class='form-group date_2'><input ... /></div>`  if I remove the div. The datepicker is not even shown

Comment: Update and fork the demo I started to reflect what you have that reproduces problem

Comment: I've update it with the <div>

Comment: Where's the forked link?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/KopbFZGGZLsIesglyGM5?p=preview

Comment: But you are initializing on `<div>` not <input>. It is possible but need to follow docs/examples to do it. Not sure what behavior you are looking for in that regard

Comment: There are no example of using div

Comment: Yes ... http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Answer (score 0):

For Disabling weekends in jQuery UI Datapicker, There is small piece of code which can help you to achieve this.

```
$(function() {
 $('#txtDate1').datepicker({ 
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends 
 });
});
```